# How can I get Icon from an app in python?

Tags: python, tkinter, icons

I'm using Python's `tkinter` module to build an Windows Explorer like app.
I used `filedialog` to open files and get their path and name, but is there a way I can also get the icon of the app to display later on my Canvas?

Does any of you know any module with some documentation I can give a look? (Or maybe ´tkinter´ already has got this feature)

This is a general question, I won't display any code (it's not necessary).

Answer (score 0):

Alternative module (richer than Tkinter) : I am using wx.Python and it works well via the command :

```py
# Icone
self.icon_path = os.path.join('icon_directory_here', 'icon32px.png')
self.SetIcon(wx.Icon(self.icon_path))
```

Maybe you would have to look for a Tkinter SetIcon method ?